# Change a single value in R?

Tags: r, indexing, tidyverse

I would like to change the "finals" to the number 4. I have tried indexing `df[4, "round"] = 4`, but that hasn't worked.  I have also tried `df[4, 2] = 4` but that hasn't worked either.  A tidyverse solution would be great if possible.  Any help is appreciated.

Some reproducible code:

```
rating <- c(1000, 900, 945, 990, 952)
round <- c(1, 2, 3, "finals", 1)

df <- data.frame(rating, round)
```

Comment: It is working fine for me.  Can you show the `str(df)`  Is it a `factor` or `character` class?  From `R 4.0`, `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is by default when you create the data.frame

Comment: If it is a `factor`, then convert to `character` before doing the assignment i.e. `df$round <- as.character(df$round)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
rating <- c(1000, 900, 945, 990, 952)
round <- c(1, 2, 3, "finals", 1)

df <- data.frame(rating, round)
df$round[4] <- 4
df$round <- as.numeric(df$round)

df
#>  rating round
#>1   1000     1
#>2    900     2
#>3    945     3
#>4    990     4
#>5    952     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue based on the class of the column i.e. a `factor` class instead of `character`.  From the `R 4.0`, the default option `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` is changed to `FALSE` in `data.frame`.  Thus, if the OP is using an older R version, the column could change to `factor`.  It can be reproduced with

```
df <- data.frame(rating, round, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

in `R 4.0.3`

Now, if we do

```
df[4, "round"] = 4
```

returns a warning and it gets converted to `NA`

> Warning message:
> In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 4, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 1L)) :
> invalid factor level, NA generated

This can be corrected by first converting the column to `character` class

```
df$round <- as.character(df$round)
```

and then using the OP's code

---

Or as the OP mentioned about `tidyverse`, we can directly recode with `fct_recode` on the `factor/character` column and then change the type (if needed)

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(round = fct_recode(round, '4' = 'finals')) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df1
#  rating round
#1   1000     1
#2    900     2
#3    945     3
#4    990     4
#5    952     1
```